# Native and fluent in english

Tags: american-english, british-english, speech, subcontinental-english

I've practised listening to english native speakers from around a year for at least 90 minutes everyday and I've practised speaking since 1 month for 1 hour every everyday and I'd like to know when can i be native ?

Comment: You can't "achieve" nativeness. It's inherent. If your mother tongue (or one of them -- I've recently learned it's possible  if rare to have multiple mother tongues) is English, and you spent most of your childhood to early adulthood speaking primarily English, you're a native English speaker. If you didn't, you aren't. That said, you certainly *can* achieve a native-like level of fluency. Many of the most senior members and moderators here on ELU have done just that. I am a native English speaker and I would never have known they weren't if they hadn't told me.

Comment: Having said all that though, to achieve a native-like level of fluency will take *years*. And probably will entail immersing yourself in a native English-speaking context, like moving to another city. One year isn't enough.

Comment: I've spoken to people who are quite fluent in English, and even after many years, most of them still use some constructions or vocabulary that mark them as not being native speakers. I've also spoken to people who I *know* are not native speakers, but who have passed as native speakers among those who do not know their history. The difference, as near as I can tell, is that those who can "pass" as native speakers have reached the point where they are _thinking_ in English, instead of thinking in their native language and translating. (This is an observation, not a statement of necessity.)

Comment: I've spoken to some native speakers that I wouldn't consider fluent in English.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Raises a good point: there is a difference between being fluent and being native. You can speak and write as if you were native just by being fluent, while a native speaker could write as if they didn't speak English at all.

Comment: When your birth certificate says so?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I personally think it is not much the case of thinking in english, for instance, some of my word choices and pronunciations can tell me apart from native speakers. I personally feel that to reach a native like level you need to spend many Years in a english only envirolment, and even so not everyone will reach it.

Comment: There is also the element of accent, and accents fade without disappearing for *decades*.  So, might as well embrace it. Trust me, French English does not sound like Tagalo English or Jamaican English.  And for Jamaicans, that is their mother tongue, but it's not American or British English.

Answer (score 1):

**You can never learn to be a native speaker, by definition.**

'Native' means that you were born in some condition. While strictly speaking nobody is born knowing a language, 'native' almost always means you grew up knowing the language, and almost always that it is your first language.

You can learn to speak a language *as well as a native speaker*. You will know that is the case when people fluent in the language interacting with you believe that you are a native speaker. It's very hard for you to tell that for yourself.

Comment: Note that I'm posting this answer because it relies on English language usage and meaning - i.e. the meaning of the word 'native'.